# Mapping and allocating

Tags: memory

I am little confused with term mapping, for example, when we say mapping memory for database, it means that we assigning specific amount of memory at some memory location to that database?

Also is allocating memory synonym for reserving memory?

Very often I encounter these two terms, and they aren't so clear to me.

If someone can clarify these two terms, I will be very thankful.

Comment: This is not about electronics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a question better asked to the software community at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). However, I am a CS.

I would say that terms aren't always used accurately and precisely.

In general allocating memory is making memory available to a program for an active purpose, such as allocating memory for buffers to hold a file or in in-memory structure *now*.

Reserving memory is often used to mean the same thing. However, it is sometimes more passive. For example reserving memory in case their is a future requirement, or protecting against too much memory allocation for a different purpose.

Often when the term 'mapping' is used, it is for a file. It may mean exactly the same as allocating. Or it means more; mapping may be using an underlying mechanism provided by virtual memory management systems, where part of virtual memory is 'mapped' to the file, without actually reading the file into physical memory. The trick is, as the memory-mapped file is accessed, the block/page being accessed is read in 'invisibly' to the process when necessary. This uses a mechanism called demand paging. It's benefit is a program can access the file as if it is all read into memory, but only the parts actually accessed are retrieved from the persistent storage system (disk, flash, whatever), which can be a huge win if only small parts of the file are needed.

Further, it simplifies the program, which can be written as if the whole file is in memory. Instead of the application developer trying to keep track of which parts of the file have been loaded into memory, the operating system does that instead.

Even better, the Operating system can be asked to track which blocks/pages have their contents changed, and it can be asked to periodically write that back out to persistent storage. This can even further simplify the application program.

This is popular with some databases.

Comment: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4070/answering-questions-which-are-off-topic

Comment: @David - I think the first part about allocation vs reservation is relevant to embedded development. However, IMHO 'mapping'  would be better migrated to stackoverflow, rather than closed. It all *might* be relevant to EE too, as increasingly there are people using more powerful CPUs (e.g. ARM A7/A8) which can support mapping; but stack overflow seem to be a better fit than here. Unfortunately, I don't know how to move it to SO.

Comment: For virtual memory, mapping is actually stronger than this -- when a file is mapped read/write, any changes to the memory are reflected *immediately* in the file as seen by any other process reading or mapping the file.  So the file acts like backing store for shared memory in this case, and you can use atomic read/modify/write instructions to synchronize between processes.

Comment: @ChrisDodd - agreed, though that seemed to be expanding the question's scope a bit too much. I can add it though, if you think it makes sense in the context of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Mapping basically means assigning. Except we often want a 1 to 1 mapping in the case of functions. If you define the function of an object, physical or just logical, and define it's relationships and how it changes under transformation then you have mapped it.